# How do I avoid recompositions affecting animations?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I have an mp3 player I`m working on, but the animations are affected by recomposition

I believe this is causing the recomposition

```
  val playbackInfo: Flow<PlaybackInfo> = combine(
    audioPlaybackRepository.currentProgress,
    audioPlaybackRepository.currentDuration
) { progress, duration ->
    PlaybackInfo.TrackInfo(
        progress = if (duration != 0L) {
            progress.toFloat() / duration.toFloat()
        } else {
            0f
        },
        duration = duration.milliseconds,
    )
}
```

It`s being called here:

```
val playbackInfo by 
mainScreenViewModel.playbackInfo.collectAsState(PlaybackInfo.Unknown)

fun BottomSheet(
    playbackInfoProvider: () -> PlaybackInfo
) {
    ...
    val progress = playbackInfoProvider().progress
    val sliderMutableInteractionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    ...
    SeekBar(
        ...
    onValueChangedFinished = {
     ...
        val positionInMS = getPositionInMs(
            sliderPosition,
            playbackInfoProvider().duration.toLong(DurationUnit.MILLISECONDS),
        )
    },
    )

    // the problem area where recompositions affect animation

    Animation(
        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
            .padding(bottom = if (isWide) 10.dp else 100.dp)
            .offset(y = if (isWide) -80.dp else 0.dp)
            .fillMaxSize(if (isWide) 0.6f else 0.85f),
        isPlaying = isPlaying,
        albumImage = currentSong?.image,
    )
}
```

This is what it causes, the composable recomposes (causing it to freeze) every time the Playback info changes:

[image]

Comment: Hi, what about following best practices: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance/bestpractices#defer-reads, which states to wrap the reading of a state in a lambda function and read within the child scope. So in your example you could read `progress` value only in `Seekbar`, not in the `BottomSheet`, which causes to recompose everything.

Comment: youre right :) thanks for the tip @CaptainJacky. I had quite a few flows that were triggering recomposition so its sorted now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recompositon was caused by not reading the flows within the composable that needed the animation like @Captain Jacky suggested :). This as causing all the composables to recompose.

Remedy:

```
    SeekBar(
    ...
onValueChangedFinished = {
 ...
    val positionInMS = getPositionInMs(
        sliderPosition,
        // the fix
        playbackInfoProvider().value.duration.toLong(DurationUnit.MILLISECONDS),
    )
},
)
```

I did the same with other composables that was adding to the recomposition.